# Absolute value property of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Show that $ |z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2| $

I have written out what $z_1$ and $z_2$ are and what $|z_1|$ and $|z_2|$ are but I still don't know how i would do it

edit: 
$z_1$ $=$ $x_1 + iy_1$ and $z_2 = x_2 +iy_2$ , so $z_1z_2$ $=$ $x_1x_2 +x_1iy_2+x_2iy_1+i^2y_1y_2$

Comment: How about writing out what $z_1z_2$ is?

Comment: [edit] the question to show us what you have "written out". Multiply those expressions and compare it to what you want.

Comment: $$|x|^2=x\cdot\bar x$$

Comment: I have written it out but I don't see how to get $|z_1||z_2|$ from it?

Comment: You have to use that $i^2 =-1$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $z\overline{z}=|z|^2$ and hence
$$
|z_1|^2|z_2|^2=z_1\overline{z_1}z_2\overline{z_2}=(z_1z_2)(\overline{z_1z_2})=|z_1z_2|^2,
$$
and hence $|z_1||z_2|=|z_1z_2|$.

Answer (score 1):

I like Dietrich Burde's answer. Here is an expansion of it.

As you have computed
$$
(x_1+iy_1)(x_2+iy_2)=(x_1x_2-y_1y_2)+i(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
|z_1z_2|^2
&=(x_1x_2-y_1y_2)^2+(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)^2\\
&=x_1^2x_2^2+y_1^2y_2^2+x_1^2y_2^2+x_2^2y_1^2\\
&=\left(x_1^2+y_1^2\right)\left(x_2^2+y_2^2\right)\\
&=|z_1|^2|z_2|^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write your equation in the form
$$|(x_1+y_1i)(x_2+y_2i)|=|x_1+y_1i||x_2+y_2i|$$